# Sharing Intent combined with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I have downloaded the Facebook SDK and set it up properly. Everything is working perfect. I can share a link or update my status without a problem. Now I want to do something else. I want to integrate both the Share Intent and the Facebook SDK in such a way that When I click on the share button in my App, the share intent should be called and a list of apps should be shown.

Now if Facebook is selected from the list, it should open up the Facebook SDK share method that I applied on the app without the share intent. If any else app is selected (Gmail/Twitter/SMS etc.) the share intent should call the respective intent normally as it does.

So far, I tried the following code:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, 
                        "http://somelink.com/somethingelse.php");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

                PackageManager pm = v.getContext().getPackageManager();

                List<ResolveInfo> activityList = 
                        pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

                for (final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {
                    if ((app.activityInfo.name).contains("facebook")) {

                        Log.d("its here:", "goood");

                        FacebookDialog shareDialog = 
                                new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder((Activity) v.getContext())
                        .setLink("http://somelink.com/somethingelse.php").build();
                        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

                        final ActivityInfo activity = app.activityInfo;
                        final ComponentName name = 
                                new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
                        sharingIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                        sharingIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                        sharingIntent.setComponent(name);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(sharingIntent);
                        break;
                    } else {
                        Log.d("shouldnt be here", "nooo");
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

I tried this code but no luck. The Share Intent is called and when I click on Facebook, it opens up a Facebook status update page where as I want it to call the Facebook SDK method that I set up and run through that method with the predefined link.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

I use Facebook SDK 4.5.1 and this method works fine with Facebook SDK 4.0+

```
ShareDialog shareDialog;
CallbackManager callbackManager;
```

in onCreateView()

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
```

in your function or code where you want to apply the share dialog.

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("Ttile")
                .setContentDescription("Description")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://somelink.com/somethingelse.php"))
                .build();
        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
     }
```

your onActivityResult() should look like this :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```

**Edit 1:** For capturing the event that user selected Facebook from the list of apps.

```
List<Intent> targetShareIntents=new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent shareIntent=new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> resInfos=context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(shareIntent, 0);

    if(!resInfos.isEmpty()){
        for(ResolveInfo resInfo : resInfos){
            String packageName=resInfo.activityInfo.packageName;

            if(packageName.contains("com.facebook.katana")){

              //Facebook sharing code

            }

        }

        if(!targetShareIntents.isEmpty()){
            Intent chooserIntent=Intent.createChooser(targetShareIntents.remove(0), "Choose app to share");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            context.startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }else{
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is fine. But is there any way to capture the event that user selected Facebook from the Share Intent.?

Comment: kindly see my `Edit1` section for the same.